# illegal use of this type as an expression in template

Tags: c++, templates

So I have been working on some kind of small Game Engine and I tried to Add Component system where basically Object has vector of Components and 2 template functions AddComponent and GetComponent. And I get error in GetComponent where I loop through vector of components and if the current components names is equal to typename component name it returns that component. Here is declaration of GetComponent:

```
template <typename T> Component GetComponent() {

    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {

        if (components[i].componentName == T.componentName) {

            return components[i];

        }

    }

    std::cout << "ERROR: GET_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND_COMPONENT" << std::endl;

}
```

I have searched at least 5 Stack Overflow articles about this error but no one used it like me. It might be something simple because I don't really understand Templates since I never used them and did just small testing to see how they work.

Comment: T.componentName you'r trying to access a member from type T not an instance of type T.  In this case I think you don't even need a template, just pass a const reference to a name into this function. Or are you trying to type GetComponent<"name">() ?

Comment: `T` is a *type*, not a value. *If* `T` has a static member `componentName`, you access it as `T::componentName`. But if it does, and assuming that `T` is one of your component types, your condition will be true for all elements. And since you're probably aiming for some polymorphism, you should have pointers in your vector. I would recommend that you start with a couple of non-templates for specific kinds of components before you try to generalize.

Comment: If no component is found, you don't `return` a `Component` and your program will have _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. It'll be hard to give a proper answer without it.

Answer (score 0):

`T::componentName` instead of `T.componentName`.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29676030)

Comment: doesn't work, it throws out these errors
`error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member

'Engine::Component::componentName'

message : see declaration of 'Engine::Component::componentName'

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Engine::Component Object::GetComponent<Engine::Transform>(void)' being compiled

error C3867: 'Engine::Component::componentName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member



error C2568: '==': unable to resolve function overload`

Comment: @ChrisHusky then it could make sense to declare componentName `static` perhaps?